# Installing WFFM with SIM - post-install steps

Tags: wffm, module, sim, installation

When installing the WFFM module with SIM, does it perform the post-install steps for you, like running the SQL script against the reporting database or updating the web.config for the captcha controls?

I noticed when I tried adding that module to a SIM install that the SIM installation eventually just hangs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SIM doesn't perform the post-install steps (running the SQL script, updating the web.config for captcha, etc...).  It does "complete", for all intents and purposes, but SIM gets stuck on the placeholder selection dialog at the end of the installation.

But apart from that, everything is installed as it should be.

Comment: Instead of installing with SIM I always prefer installing via package.